# get inserted row after doing an insert query?

Tags: php, mysql

So what i'm basically doing is that i wanna redirect user to `art.php?id=$id` right after the insert function so for example:

so here is my `$user->insertArt` function anyways:

```
public function insertArt($description,$image,$creator,$width,$height){
    try {
        $sql = "INSERT into arts (description,id,image,creator,post_date,width,height) values (:description,UUID_SHORT(),:image,:creator,NOW(),:width,:height)";
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':description',$description,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':image',$image,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':creator',$creator,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':width' , $width, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':height' , $height, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        return true;
     }catch(PDOException $e){echo $e->errorInfo; return false;}
}
```

so what i'm trying to do is like below and replace `$id` with something to get the id row from the `$user->in`.

```
if ($user->insertArt($description, $image['url'], $creator, $width, $height)) {
    unlink(realpath('uploads/' . $newFileName));
    //redirect user to the ID.
    header("Location:art.php?id=$id"); // replace $id with UUID_SHORT from the query
}
}
```

Comment: After you execute, get the last id... $stmt->lastInsertID(). That is a PDO function to return the last id it inserted. And then return that id instead of true.

Comment: Does the linked answer really work for MySQL?

Comment: @MartavisGriffin A little error there, the method should be called on the database-object, not the statement, like `$this->con->lastInsertID();` http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php - in `mysqli_`, it's on the statement-object though ;-)

Comment: Use `LAST_INSERT_ID(UUID_SHORT())` in your query. And then PDOs `lastInsertID()` function.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel where do i add last_insert_id? in the insert query? can you type code? (answer)

Comment: nvm i fixed it using @MartavisGriffin